# python conditional debug breakpoint one-liner for versions before 3.7 PEP 553 that acts similarly to Perl's $DB::single=1

Tags: python, perl, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-execution

In python versions before PEP 553 `breakpoint()` utility, what is the recommended way to add (ideally a one-liner) code to have a breakpoint that can be ignored upon a condition (e.g. a global debug flag or args.debug flag).

In Perl, I am used to use `$DB::single=1;1;` single-lines, which I know I can safely leave in the code and won't affect the normal running of `perl code.pl` unless explicitly calling `perl -d code.pl`. E.g.:

```
my $a = 1;
$DB::single=1;1; # breakpoint line
my $b = 2;
print "$a $b\n";
```

If I run this code as: `perl code.pl`, it will run to completion.
If I run this code with: `perl -d code.pl`, the `pdb` will stop at the breakpoint line (not before the next line with a `my $b = 2;` statement) because it contains a `1;` statement after the `$DB::single=1;` statement;

Similarly, if I write:

```
my $debug = 1;
my $a = 1;
$DB::single=$debug;1; # first breakpoint line
my $b = 2;
$DB::single=$debug;1; # second breakpoint line
print "$a $b\n";
# [...] Lots more code sprinkled with more of these
$DB::single=$debug;1; # n'th breakpoint line
```

I can then execute `perl -d code.pl`, which will stop in the first breakpoint line, then in the `pdb` session, once I am happy that it does not need stopping anywhere else, then execute: `$debug = 0`, then `pdb` continue `c`, which will make it not stop at the second or other similar breakpoint lines in the code.

How can I achieve the same, ideally in single-line statements, in python (2.x and 3.x before PEP 553)?

I am aware of PEP 553 and apart from the hassle of having to explicitly set `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0 python3.7 code.py` or comment out the `breakpoint()` lines, it is a solution to the question here.

I thought of options like:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
dummy=None;
```

The statement underneath `pdb.set_trace()` is so that I can achieve the same as the `1;` in the same line after `$DB::single=1;` in Perl, which is to have the debugger stop where I placed the breakpoint, rather than the next statement. This is so that if there are large chunks of commented code or documentation in-between, the debugger does not jump to the next statement far away from the breakpoint.

Or with conditionals like:

```
if args.debug or debug:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    _debug=False; #args.debug=False
```

So that if I am done debugging for a script, I can set `args.debug=False` or `debug=False` and not have to touch all these breakpoints in the code.

Comment: In case you're still interested in reciving an answer, is there something missing from my post that's necessary for you to pass as acceptable?

Answer (score 7):

#### Setting a conditional breakpoint

Same as perl, python can be run with `-d` to set a debug flag:

```sh
$ python --help
[...]
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
[...]
```

You can check its state during runtime via `sys.flags` :

```sh
$ python -d
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.flags
sys.flags(debug=1, py3k_warning=0, division_warning=0, ...)
#         ^ there it is, right at the front
```

Which allows for the following one-liner to enable debugging:

```py
import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace() if sys.flags[0] else None
```

---

#### Disabling conditional breakpoints from the debugger

Regarding this part

> [...] once I am happy that it does not need stopping anywhere else, then execute [something] which will make it not stop at the second or other similar breakpoint lines in the code.

it gets a little trickier though, since python doesn't allows mutation of [the `flags` structure](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-struct-sequence), or even creating an instance of it:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.flags.debug = 0                 # no mutating ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: readonly attribute
>>> type(sys.flags)()                   # ... and no instanciating
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'sys.flags' instances
```

But as far as I have tested, unless you run python with other flags, the following works to deactivate subsequent traces without altering your program's other behavior:

```py
import sys; sys.flags = [0]*len(sys.flags)  # even fits onto a single line
```

---

For a slightly more robust monkey patch that you should use in case the former one leads to strange bugs, you'll need to have something like this:

```py
def untrace():
  """Call this function in the pdb session to skip debug-only set_trace() calls"""
  import re
  import sys
  from collections import namedtuple  # has the same interface as struct sequence
  sys.flags = namedtuple(
    'sys_flags', 
    [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'\w{2,}', repr(sys.flags)[10:-1])]
  )(0, *sys.flags[1:])
```

While this statement *can* be put on a single line, it's probably a little too much. You can either paste this function into the `.py` file where you plan to use it, or have some kind of `utils.py` from which you import it during debugging, after which a c(ontinue) should again run the rest of the program:

```py
(Pdb) import utils; utils.untrace()
(Pdb) c
```

Comment: I didn't include anything about how to start the session before the next line, since I don't have something useful to add. But as a side note, it might be a little more idiomatic to use `...` (the [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) object) as a dummy statement instead of `dummy = None`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way using a `.pdbrc` file in the current directory:

**t.py**

```
def my_trace():
    global debug
    if debug:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

debug = True
a= 1
my_trace()
b = 2
c = 3
my_trace()
d = 4
```

**.pdbrc**:

```
r
```

**Example session**:

```
$ python t.py
--Return--
> [...]/t.py(12)<module>()
-> b = 2
(Pdb) p a
1
(Pdb) p b
*** NameError: name 'b' is not defined
(Pdb) !debug=False
(Pdb) c
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like pdb jumps to the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line when I run the script, rather than staying outside of `my_trace()`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Strange, it works for me (Python 3.7.1). Did you save the `.pdbrc` in the current directory? It won't work without it and the `r` (`return`) command

Comment: Ah! Apologies, I was running python 2.x instead of python 3.x. I now got it to work with the behavior that you describe when using python 3.4.3 (old Ubuntu 14.04 laptop). Last thing is to be able to have a single line equivalent to `$DB::single=1;1;` so the pdb pointer stops in the `my_trace()` line rather than in the line with a statement *after* the `my_trace()` line.

Comment: Seems like it is not possible to add statements at the same line as in Perl, and have the debugger respect that as separate statements. The only thing I could suggest is to add a line below `my_trace()`. For example a dummy statement like: `debug = debug` should work